# `If` clause with observable parameter

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I am assigning a value to a variable `x` as so:

```
var x = (self.SelectedItem.EanCode() != self.ItemForEditing.EanCode()) && (self.ItemForEditing.ChildProducts().length > 0 || self.ItemForEditing.ParentProductId);
```

At runtime, x looks like:

[image]

I am then doing the following checks:

[image]

And still, If I then call `if(x) { alert('dsds') }`, the alert pops up. Why is this? What does the actual comparison that `if` does look like? Is this knockout-related? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a set of parens from `self.ItemForEditing.ParentProductId` it should be `self.ItemForEditing.ParentProductId()` then x will contain the correct bool value

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. Still, I don't understand why would x get assigned anything but a bool when doing `var x = y && z`, no matter what y or z are.

Comment: "var x = a && (b || c)" - a is true, b is false => x = c. "c" is observable, so "x" is not boolean, but function with "null" result